# Stop Word from adding spacing on "page break"

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office

In MS Word, I've set my "normal" template to 0 spacing before and after a paragraph, and "Line spacing" to "Single" (I also changed the character to Times New Roman). However, every time I insert a page break, the `----page break----` "character" will have 8pt spacing "after", and "Line Spacing" at 1.08. This will happen even if I am currently using use the predefined "No spacing" style.

[image: MS Word Page Break Style issue]

The same thing happens also if I choose a different Style, such as (Default Word out of the box) Heading 1 Style:

[image: MS Word Page Break Style issue - different styling]

If I subsequently need to enter text at the bottom of an existing page (that is: right before or after a line break character) this new text will retain the spacing, messing up my layout. I can reset this in the paragraph options, but it's cumbersome, as this happens to me several times a day.

**Is there any way to "teach" Word that I never ever want any extra spaces before/after or Multiple Line Spaces ??** I could live with "never ever, in all my docs from here to eternity".

Just applying the "No Spacing" style isn't a solution, as it also resets any specific styling such as `bold`, `ìtalics`, text color ecc.

I currently use MS Word 365, but the problem persists since MS Word 2010.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've just come across this thread when someone came to me with the same issue. I did a bit of testing it out and I've solved the issue. When you use Ctrl + Enter it uses the default MS +Body style for the page break. To fix it, you need to change the +Body spacing.

1. Open the style pane
2. Click Manage Styles
3. Click Set Defaults
4. Make sure +Body is selected, then change the paragraph spacing as required

[image: Image showing screenshot of Word with the steps]

Comment: Thank you. This has been bugging me for years and had always needed a workaround. Now it's resolved. I'll be awarding you a bounty for that. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

Use shift and enter to prevent the extra spacing. This was the only way that I could prevent this happening.

Comment: `Shift+Ctrl+Enter` inserts a column break, which in many cases is good enough, so thanks for the tip. But I still need to do a page break as described.

Answer (score 2):

When you add the page break from Insert -> Pages -> Page Break, this is what you get:

[image]

It is analogous to pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>. But if done from Layout -> Page Setup -> Breaks -> Page, you get this:

[image]

No need to change the spacing. it creates the page break where the cursor is/was without adding a space.

[image]